# Track only the HTC Controllers without the Headset itself

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, htc-vive

Im trying to track only the HTC Controllers without the Headset itself, I Don't want a VR View but i need to track the controllers. I tried disabling everything from the steamvr plugin and keeping only the controllers but that doesn't work, because if the Camera doesn't work the tracking for controllers won't happen. Is there any way to throw away the VR camera and just track the controllers?

Im working On Unity 5.5

Comment: what you only want controller not camera head? why. Is there any other simple camera in scene?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue. if anyone outthere just want to track the controllers and not the head, then you need to disable the "Target Eye" Property on your normal camera and set it to "None" Because you have your project as VR supported the normal camera will turn into VR and Unity will search for Oculus or SteamVR and make your camera VR. therefore you need to disable the target eye in the camera

Comment: That stops the tracking but also stops the rendering to the HTC Vive.. We want rendering but no tracking